# Lower bound on tail when $\mathbb E[X] = \infty$

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X$ be a real valued random variable whose expectation does not exist ($\mathbb E [X] = \infty$). Derive a lower bound for $\mathbb P( X > t)$ where $t$ is any positive constant.

I expect that such a bound exists in general, although I am not sure, since I am having trouble deriving one. Intuitively, $\mathbb E [X] = \infty$ means that for every $\tau > 0$, the measure of $\{X>\tau\}$ is "large enough". I'm having trouble making this statement quantitative and useful for a lower bound.

Comment: Is it asking for "a lower bound on $\mathbb P(X>t)$ for all $t$ sufficiently large"? I.e.: find an $f(t)$ and a $T$ such that $\mathbb P(X>t)\geq f(t)$ for all $t\geq T$. Is that what the question is?

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but if all you know is that $E[X]=\infty$, then the only lower bound on $P(X>\tau)$ is zero. Pick large $\tau>0$ and small $\varepsilon>0$ and consider a random variable $X$ with survival function
$$P(X>x)=\frac{\varepsilon\tau}{2x},\qquad x\ge\tau.$$ (For $x<\tau$ the survival function can be anything.)
Then $E[X]=\infty$ while $P(X>\tau)<\varepsilon$.